Let $B\subsetneqq A\subset\mathbb{N}$. If there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$, then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$.
I am reading "Logic in Mathematics and Set Theory" (in Japanese) by Kazuyuki Tanaka and Toshio Suzuki.
This book is not a rigorous book.

Verify the following fact holds.
Let $B\subsetneqq A\subset\mathbb{N}$.
If there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$, then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

I know Dedekind defined a set $S$ is infinite if there exists a bijection from $S$ to $T\subsetneqq S$.
My attempt is here:
Assume that $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is finite.
Then the number of the elements of $A$ is greater than the number of the elements of $B$ since $B\subsetneqq A$.
So, there is no injection from $A$ to $B$.
So, there is no bijection from $A$ to $B$.
So, $A$ is infinite if there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B\subsetneqq A$.
Let $a_0$ be the smallest element of $A$.
Let $a_1$ be the smallest element of $A\setminus\{a_0\}$.
Let $a_2$ be the smallest element of $A\setminus\{a_0,a_1\}$.
$\cdots$
Then, $\{0,1,2,\dots\}\ni i\mapsto a_i\in A$ is obviously injective.
Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A$.
Suppose $a$ is the $i$-th smallest element of $A$.
Then, $a=a_i$.
So, $\{0,1,2,\dots\}\ni i\mapsto a_i\in A$ is surjective.
I don't satisfy this "proof".
How to prove the above fact sufficiently rigorously?

The proof you've written is correct (though it could be more detailed). Which parts seem insufficiently rigorous to you?

@AlexKruckman thank you very much for your comment. I cannot say which parts I feel insufficiently rigorous. But I guessed a person who knows the foundations of mathematics will say this is not rigorous.

Using the well-ordering of the natural numbers seems superfluous here.  If $B$ is finite then there could not be a bijection with $A$ since $A$ properly contains $B$.  Now that $B$ is infinite, $A$ is also infinite and then both are necessarily countable and hence equinumerous with $\mathbb N$.  If you have limitations on set-theoretic material one can use in the proof, you should make them more explicit in your question.

Mikhail Katz, thank you very much for your answer.

You say "then both are necessarily countable". But the proof that every infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable is exactly the one given by @佐武五郎 using the well-ordering.

Alternatively, of course, one can argue that if $A$ is infinite, $\mathbb{N}$ injects into $A$, so if $A$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $A$ is countable by CSB. But at the level the OP is working at, it seems this requires an argument as well.
